# Setting up virtual network in VMware workstation

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I am playing around with VMware workstation and am trying to set up a small virtual network. I am having a little trouble with this I hope somebody can help me out.

I want to have all the different virtual machines to have different internal IP adresses so I can ping them SSH etc, from within my windows machine.

I am directly connected to the internet without a router, so using a bridged connection does not seem to work. The other options NAT and host-only do not seem to work also. I think i need to create a new adapter.

I am testing this out with a virtual image of linux debain 5.0 lenny.

I have WMware Workstation 7 with virtual network editor.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Can I ask why you're connected to the Internet without a router?  Pretty scary if you ask me.

Comment: Yes I am aware this is a risk. I have my reasons, but thank you for the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want the guest machines to be able to access the Internet? If yes, then you want the NAT option. If no, then host-only should be sufficient to access them from the host. What about these options makes you think they will not work for you?

EDIT:

If you use the NAT mode, then you should be able to connect to the internet on the guest machines, providing you have them configured correctly (IPs in the correct range, correct gateway, etc.). Are you using a default installation of VMware workstation? If you configure the guests to be on the `NAT` network, and set them to DHCP, do they get addresses? If you can't use DHCP, you can use the VMware Virtual Network Editor to determine what IP range they should be on (check the `NAT` tab for the gateway IP address and the netmask, then assign them IPs in the same range--but not .1, as that is the host).

EDIT2:

To view the ip information on debian, run `ifconfig -a`.

--jed

Comment: Ok I want to be able to connect to the internet on all the machines. If I use host-only, there is no connection. If I use NAT then I am not able to internally. Or would I? I do not know how to view the internal IP on debian, IPCONFIG is not working.

Comment: @Saif what did you do to make it work?

Comment: Configured the guest system as NAT, and then booted the machine. I used the ifconfig -a to get the exact ip from the guest. Now I can locally work in the machine. I guess the command ifconfig was throwing me off.